# Extensibilty,maintainability and re-usability oop concepts

Tags: java, oop

Can anyone explain me what the extensibiliy, maintainability and re-usability (OOP concepts)

Comment: sounds like an assignment. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Extensibility - Ease of adding new features to an existing codebase.

Maintainability - Ease of reading and understanding the existing codebase to easily debug, optimize and refactor it.

Reusability - Ease of using previously created code in order to reduce redundancy and repetition in your code.

Comment: i coudn't get Reusability :/ seems like "Reusablity" can be implemented with in functional program paradigm. even with C language we can  use previously created code in order to reduce redundancy and repetition.

Comment: You are correct. Reusability is independent of programming languages. Reusability depends on how you structure your code whether it be C, C++, LISP, etc.